# Why do variables with large values influence PCA stronger?

Tags: pca

In principal component analysis, the loadings are weights which are used to transform (linearly) the original values.

If the values are values of gene expression, then

`gene1 expression*weight of gene1 + ... + geneN expression*weight of geneN = the value of the sample on the PC.`

====

The above is a summary of what I know.

Why in data that has not been scaled will the variables (genes) with higher expression influence a PC more strongly and have larger loadings?

Since loadings are the weights of each gene, from the above it seems that variables with large expression values will "need" a small weight to influence a PC.

Comment: Could you please specify what a "loading for a specific PC" means?

Comment: @mhdadk I have omitted this wording. It is not necessary for the question.